# How durable is laptop cover to protect LCD screen reliably?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron, lcd

How durable is laptop cover to protect LCD screen reliably? Although Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series laptop cover looks durable enough, is it fully safe have 5-6 kg weight placed on the top of cover? Cat took a fancy to my laptop to sleep on the top. Laptop is in the neoprene sleeve.

Comment: The Dell technical reference material doesn't specify the maximum weight cat that can sleep on the laptop without damage.  What you're doing is called "destructive testing".  Keep track of your cat's weight, and when your laptop finally breaks, please return and post an answer as the the maximum safe weight.  Consider buying or making a riser that you slide the laptop under when it's not in use.  That will be much cheaper than discovering the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this laptop model specifically, but I can say that most laptops can easily support the weight of a house cat napping on it. It would be a good idea though to keep the cat away from your electronics.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series. If extra weight is placed on the top of laptop lid for whatever reason, I assume it may cause LCD screen damage, as weakest component. The average sized adult cat weigh is about of 5-6kg (11-13 pounds): is this pressure still safe for LCD screen?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, it should very well be ok. But I do not recommend letting your cat sleep on your electronics. It may be just fine for the first 100 times and one days the weight is at the wrong place and it could break.